# Copying from NFS mount crashes Linux client machine

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs, kernel-panic

I have NFS share mounted on CLIENT in /etc/fstab:

```
SERVER:/share on /mnt/share type nfs (rw,users,noexec,nosuid,nodev,timeo=14,hard,intr,addr=1.2.3.4)
```

Intensive use on client like copying a lot of data from it crashes the host after a few minutes.

`/etc/exports` on SERVER:

```
/nfsshare  1.2.3.4(rw,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Sometimes (not always) I get on CLIENT:

```
messages:Nov 18 16:28:09 CLIENT kernel: nfs: server SERVER not responding, still trying
```

Client data:

```
Linux CLIENT 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 13 09:21:40 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
% cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
```

Server often (though not always) displays smth like:

```
Nov 18 16:04:07 SERVER kernel: rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: sent only 943052 when sending 1048708 bytes - shutting down socket
```

What is the reason of crashing? And how I can fix that?

Comment: This can occur with a heavily loaded NFS server - TCP is more resource heavy than UDP - hence you might start by using UDP if server and client don't have dynamic address translation in between.